# JavaScript try/catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, try-catch

```
export const getData = async (locationId) => {
  try {
    return await axios.get(`/api/data/?lotion=${locationId}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR', error);
  }
};
```

So I have function getData where I added try/catch block.That function is called in another component in componentDidMount() and its all working if endpoint is correct but if I try to make error its not running my catch block. I mistyped my endpoint the correct one is `/api/data/?location=${locationId}` I have done that to get error and I get error 400 Bad Request. So the problem is that my code never run my catch block and it doesn't console.log Error.

I found similar problem on internet and they said that async/await must be added I also added that but still not working...

Any ideas?

Comment: If it logs the 400 code. Then your catch block is working fine.

Comment: POST 400 (Bad Request) is not an error  (You mess up your request) .catch only fire if there is a problem with your response. If you want to check for Bad request.. Use the status field.